# StackOverFlowException when entity is sent by EJB bean

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I am trying to get a list of entities from EJB bean as a result of query. Actually at most time, I am not getting any exception.But for some entities, I am getting StackOverFlow exceptions.I did not get why it occurs.If my jpa entity model were wrong, I think I would get this exception every time.

```
error: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$HandleTable.hash(ObjectOutputStream.java:2330) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$HandleTable.lookup(ObjectOutputStream.java:2263) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$ReplaceTable.lookup(ObjectOutputStream.java:2369) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1093) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:570) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor335.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:570) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor335.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:570) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor335.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:570) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor335.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_30]
```

Comment: Is the problem reproducible from time to time when: 1) the same query results are retrieved all the time, 2) various query results are retrieved? Maybe some of the entity instances contain data that lead to the exception? It could probably be helpful to see how involved entities and query are defined.

Comment: The problem is reproducible every time for a specific entity id.So I think second option.

Comment: Then it might be somehow related with Arraylist (i.e. part of relationship).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that My JPA model was wrong.  FetchType.EAGER in one relationship causes StackOverFLowEception. I changed it to FetchType.LAZY.